# A child is climbing up a staircase with n steps, and can hop either 1 step, 2 steps, or 3 steps (only once per session)

Tags: java

I have a school assignment and I dont know what to do.
Here is the question:

> A child is climbing up a staircase with n steps, and can hop either 1 step, 2 steps, or 3 steps (only once per session) at a time. Implement a method to count how many possible ways the child can jump up the stairs

I know how to write a code with constant number of jumps' however don't know how to make that the 3 step jump made only once per session.

I have a boolean value which I must use and I don't get what.

```
static int climb3(int n, boolean can) {
      if (n < 0)
            return 0;
        else if (n == 0)
            return 1;
        else if(can==false)
            return climb3(n - 1,can) + climb3(n - 2,can) + climb3(n - 3,can);
}
```

How do I shut down climb 3 after one use to not count it?
Thanks!

Comment: You have to clarify what `can` means. ie what does "per session" mean?

Comment: I would look into permutations and combinations.  This is a permutation: the order of hops matters when counting.

Comment: @AaronCarson - Yes ... but the "only once per session" makes the mathematics more complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep going.  You are nearly there:

Hint: you need a final "branch: in your "if else if ..." chain to deal with the `can == true` case.

Hint 2:  Assuming `can == false` means you can't make a 3 step jump, then you have the recursion incorrect for that case.

---

Solution:  (not tested)

```
static int climb3(int n, boolean canMake3stepJump) {
    if (n < 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if (canMake3stepJump) {
        return climb3(n - 1, true) + climb3(n - 2, true) + 
               climb3(n - 3, false);
    } else {
        return climb3(n - 1, false) + climb3(n - 2, false);
    }
}
```

I advise you to try to understand how the recursion works in the case where `canMake3stepJump` is `true`.  It might help to write out the tree of recursive calls.

Comment: I still dont get the point. I cant understend how to I calculate the correct combination. And how do I tell the program to use only one the 3 step jump.

Comment: 1)  This is a permutation problem.  Order matters.  2)  In the call that uses the 3-step jump, you pass `false` as the `can` value ... and that should propagate throughout that subtree of the search space.  That also explains why you need separate `can == true` and `can == false` cases.

Comment: I do understand that. The thing that I don't is - how do I change the value of can to fals after one use.

Comment: You don't change it.  You pass it (`false`) on to the next level of recursion.  Think carefully about what the >>local<< value of `can` actually means at any point in the recursion ...

Comment: as i understood it must be like this: if(can==true) return climb3(n - 1,false) + climb3(n - 2,false) + climb3(n - 3,false); else return climb3(n - 1,false) + climb3(n - 2,false); at the beginning the program passes the first if because of the Boolean true, however every next tile it cant pass due to false value. am i correct? by the way, the answer is incorrect and i dont really understand what to modify